# Not able to pass authentication header in axios along with bodyFormData

Tags: reactjs, authentication, django-rest-framework, axios

I am trying to make comment functionality using react and django rest framework where only authenticated users can comment on blogs. The same i am able to achieve using Postman but it is not working when I tried using axios from react app. It is showing Authenticated details not provided despite of user is logged in.

Here what I have done so far using axios

```
export const blogPrimaryCommentCreate = (type, slug, content) => (dispatch, getState) => {

    var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('content', content);

    axios
        .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments/create/`, bodyFormData, { params: { type, slug } }, tokenConfig(getState))
        .then(res => {
            dispatch(createMessage({ commentSuccess: 'Thank You. Comment has been submited to Moderator' }));
            dispatch({
                type: CREATE_BLOG_PRIMARY_COMMENT,
                payload: res.data
            });

        })
        .catch(err =>
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
        );
};



export const tokenConfig = getState => {
    // Get token from state
    const token = getState().auth.token;


    // Headers

    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"

        }
    };

    // If token, add to headers config
    if (token) {
        config.headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
};
```

Here is error details from Chrome Dev tool under network tab

```
##General##
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments/create/?type=articles&slug=my-second-blog-my-second-blog-my-second-blog-my-se
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

##Response Header##
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 06 Sep 2019 20:27:34 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.1
Vary: Accept, Cookie, Origin
WWW-Authenticate: Token
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN


##Request Header##
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary4Ex7moZAQ1BAIDFT
DNT: 1
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/blogs/my-second-blog-my-second-blog-my-second-blog-my-se
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Mobile Safari/537.36
type: articles


##Query String Parameter##
slug: my-second-blog-my-second-blog-my-second-blog-my-se
content: dfg


##Form Data##
Test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the header as a fourth parameter, but it's part of the same object of `params`.

Here is the method signature: `axios#post(url[, data[, config]])`

Just update your request to:

```
axios.post(URL, bodyFormData, { params: { type, slug }, ...tokenConfig(getState) })
```